# Python/Django: Unable to return list elements line by line

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I am trying to filter cities from a json file and showup first five cities from the filtered list with a help of Django app.

But when I'm trying to return list element in HTTPResponse line by line, it gives me everything in single line.

views.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import re
import os
from django.conf import settings

def index(request):
    a= str(request.GET['city'])
    with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'all_city_info.json')) as f:
        data = f.read()

    lis=sorted(x[9:-1] for x in re.findall('"text": "'+re.escape(a)+'[\s\S]+?"', data))
    return HttpResponse('\n'.join([str(x) for x in lis[:5]]))
```

Input is being taken from the user in city variable like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?city=New

Result which i get:

> New York Mills|Minnesota|United States New York Mills|New York|United
>   States New York|New York|United States New York|Norfolk|United Kingdom

Please advise, what shall i do so that I get cities in line on browser when I return HTTPResponse.

Thanks!

Sample data, if anybody want's to take a look-

> {"City": {"values": [{"text": "Abee|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB",
>   "id": 21774}, {"text": "Acadia Valley|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB",
>   "id": 21775}, {"text": "Acme|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id":
>   21776}, {"text": "Airdrie|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id":
>   21777}, {"text": "Alderson|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id":
>   21778}, {"text": "Alix|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21779},
>   {"text": "Alliance|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21780},
>   {"text": "Andrew|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21781},
>   {"text": "Ardmore|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21782},
>   {"text": "Ardrossan|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21783},
>   {"text": "Ashmont|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21784},
>   {"text": "Athabasca|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21785},
>   {"text": "Atikameg|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21786},
>   {"text": "Atmore|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21787},
>   {"text": "Avenir|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21788},
>   {"text": "Balzac|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21789},
>   {"text": "Banff|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21790}, {"text":
>   "Barons|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21791}, {"text":
>   "Barrhead|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21792}, {"text":
>   "Bashaw|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21793}, {"text":
>   "Bassano|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21794}, {"text":
>   "Beaumont|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21795}, {"text":
>   "Beaverlodge|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21796}, {"text":
>   "Beiseker|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21797}, {"text":
>   "Bellevue|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21798}, {"text":
>   "Bellis|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21799}, {"text":
>   "Benalto|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21800}, {"text":
>   "Bentley|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21801}, {"text":
>   "Bergen|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21802}, {"text":
>   "Berwyn|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21803}, {"text": "Big
>   Valley|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21804}, {"text":
>   "Bilby|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21805}, {"text": "Bittern
>   Lake|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21806}, {"text": "Black
>   Diamond|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21807}, {"text":
>   "Blackfalds|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21808}, {"text":
>   "Blackie|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21809}, {"text":
>   "Blairmore|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21810}, {"text":
>   "Blue Ridge|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21811}, {"text":
>   "Bluesky|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21812}, {"text":
>   "Bluffton|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21813}, {"text": "Bon
>   Accord|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21814}, {"text":
>   "Bonnyville|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21815}, {"text":
>   "Bowden|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21816}, {"text": "Bow
>   Island|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21817}, {"text":
>   "Boyle|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21818}, {"text":
>   "Brampton|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21819}]}}

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to parse the json string at some point using the `json` module?

Comment: That was increasing the execution time of the program so I did it this way.

Comment: It might increase the execution time but it's the right thing to do. So unless you actually can measure/proove the runtime is a real problem please don't use such ugly hacks.

Comment: @BlackJack The execution time was a problem actually, Earlier it was 0.35 secs to filter out cities from a file of 12 mb but my manager wanted me to make it below 0.05 and I tried regular expression, it came to be 0.03 sec with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` does not mean anything in your `HTML` response. Use the `<br>` tag to separate lines instead.

Comment: @Sanchit Alternatively you could set the content type to _text/plain_, then the '\n' has meaning again. :-)